# How to run my created java program to my pc

Tags: java

I'm using Dialog Boxes in java. How do i apply this to my computer? just asking
I'm not very good enough. please help me.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class dialogs{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a complete tutorial to learn.

Comment: Is it hard? Sorry im just a newbie. can you send some links?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do as a program (Website, Software, Phone Application). In any case, it is better to learn with an IDE and the console how it works before switching to a graphical interface.

Comment: Thanks. Lets just say I want to program a website. Can you help me find a good tutorial video?

Comment: I advise you to search the tutorial in your native language. Even mastering English, there are many things to see and it's easier like that. But to do a website see the tutorials about **JavaEE** not Java. It's different because JavaEE have a lot of features web-oriented.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options depending on your IDE. I would suggest you try to either run your code directly from the IDE, which is usually possible. Or you export your code to a runnable .jar file. To run this file, navigate to the directory where you exported it to via the command promt and enter `java -jar dialogs.jar` (if you named the exported file differently, use a different file name).